# Sort Datagridview by Two Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview that contain 3 columns. But I hv not bind a datasource to datagridview.
It has three columns.

### EmpName,InTime,OutTime

I can edit EmpName in datagridview.

I want to sort the content in the datagridview after i edit a row.

I want to sort first by EmpName and then by InTime.
The time is in AM , PM Time format (Ex: 2:00 PM).

I can sort data by only one column.
I have used,

```
dgvSchedule.Sort(dgvSchedule.Columns[0],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

But how to sort by multiple columns. Specially when the time is in AM PM format.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the overload `Sort(IComparer)` to achieve your goal.

Comment: How to do that.. i hv no idea. Please help.

Comment: Refer to this link it will help, it implements ICompare interface, and uses Sort method as said above.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `IComparer` somehow like this:

```
private class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
    private static int SortOrder = 1;

    public CustomComparer(SortOrder sortOrder)
    {
        SortOrder = sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? 1 : -1; 
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        int result = row1.Cells["EmpName"].Value.ToString().CompareTo(
                                    row2.Cells["EmpName"].Value.ToString());

        if ( result == 0 )
        {
            result = DateTime.ParseExact(
                         row1.Cells["InTime"].Value.ToString(),
                         "h:mm tt",
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay
                   .CompareTo(
                     DateTime.ParseExact(
                         row2.Cells["InTime"].Value.ToString(),
                         "h:mm tt",
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
        }

        return result * SortOrder;
    }
```

Usage is:

```
dgvSchedule.Sort(new CustomComparer(ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```