# How to sort datagridview columns if you have the same value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program like a quiz game. Now in my datagridview I successfully sorted by descending the column score. Now my problem is what if I have the same value? How can I sort it and base the sorting to another column?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your question doesnt make much sense

Comment: See [how to sort a datagridview by 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8891390/3773066) for a `DataTable` example or [Sort Datagridview by Two Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21728420/3773066) for an `IComparer` example, or [numerous other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datagridview+sort+multiple+columns).